# Passing data to blueimp gallery

Tags: javascript, gallery, parameter-passing, blueimp

I'm trying to pass data to my blueimp gallery that will allow me to display the user's photo and their user name to the right of the photo. I have all the styling set up but I can't get the url profile images to pass through. This is what I currently have: (yes, I have look at the other questions that are similar but those error as well.)

Passing in:

```
<a href="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-frc/t51.2885-15/10354419_326636454151829_1909985918_n.jpg" title="Snapped a good one while I was downtown today. #basilicaofsaintmary #minneapolis #blockparty #july11-12" data-gallery="" data-prof-pic="http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1327603941_75sq_1400444292.jpg" data-username="username">
    <img src="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-frc/t51.2885-15/10354419_326636454151829_1909985918_a.jpg" style="width:250px; height:250px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    </a>
```

Wanting to load it into:

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="modal-prof-pic" style="float:right; width:30%;">
                    <span id="insert-prof-pic"></span>
                    <h3>username</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body next">
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                        Previous
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                        Next
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <h5>You may also use your arrow keys to navigate</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want the url image to go into the `<span id="insert-prof-pic"></span>` so I've tried using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var gallery = blueimp.Gallery(
        document.getElementById('photo_stream links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        {
            container: '#blueimp-gallery',
            carousel: false,
            onslide: function (index, slide) {
                var prof_pic = this.list[index].getAttribute('data-prof-pic');
                document.getElementById('insert-prof-pic').innerHTML = '<img src="'+prof_pic+'">';
        }
        }
    );




</script>
```

When I load the page, it opens up automatically and has the profile picture there but when I try to slide around the gallery to look at other photos, its all broken. Then if I exit the gallery and select another image, the profile picture doesn't show up.

Simple: I would just like to be able to pass data into the gallery's view from an a href into a span with a single id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you should select your elements by using a .class because the span element is not unique , it will be replicated , it's in a for loop for every image. make it  and code:

```
var prof_pic = this.list[index].getAttribute('data-prof-pic');
var node = this.container.find('.insert-prof-pic');
node[0].innerHTML = '<img src="'+prof_pic+'">';
```